# I installed scapy but it will not run by entering scapy in cmd prompt

Tags: python

I installed scapy without any problems but when I try to run in cmd prompt by entering scapy and hitting enter, I get two error messages. I have attempted to add the usual paths but no success. Error message follows:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\adamh>scapy
INFO: Can't import python gnuplot wrapper . Won't be able to plot.
INFO: Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump().

C:\Users\adamh>
```

Thank you all for any help offered, I sincerely appreciate it.

This is and edited update, I discovered that on windows you need scapy 2 because it supports windows, and it works with python 2.7. Also I needed to install the following list of prerequisite software first with different install techniques.

1: WinPcap, dnet, and pcap from .exe
2:pyreadline, and pywin through pip install
3:pyx through pip install using pyx==0.12.1  command
4:gnu through manual install using cmd prompt after changing root directory ect.. as usual

Then I used the from scapy.all import *   command in the python27 IDE.
After this scapy was up and running from cmd prompt using scapy and hitting enter. Thank you all and I hope this post helps someone else. Note that scapy is best used with Linux systems. Back to my C++ books yall, peace.

Comment: I have also tried restarting after modifying system path. Still same error message.

Comment: It also had no problems importing in python IDE.

Comment: Did u try the steps in http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#windows

Comment: Yes I followed them but after successful installation and test by importing scapy in python IDE scapy still failed to run.

Comment: What python version do you use?

Comment: Possibly you should try `conda` for installation on windows as it's stated in https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the latest versions (RC candidates on PyPy or dev versions at https://github.com/secdev/scapy)

In my case, it fixed tons of console glitches